# What is the syntax to put block of code into getOrElse method?

Tags: scala

I want to place a block of a code into getOrElse method, but I can't:

```
   //1
    getOrElse(() => {
      println("id is not found: " + x.Id)
      new MyClass(-1)
   })

   //2
    getOrElse {
      println("id is not found: " + x.Id)
      new MyClass(-1)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
scala> None getOrElse { println("AAA")
     | 5 }
AAA
res1: Int = 5
```

BTW, `{ () => ... }` is a function from the empty argument set to something.

Answer (score 0):

Probably here You have problems :

new MyClass(-1)

I dont see much code but this problems.
See this code which works fine:

```
import scala.io.Source

class Test(x: Int) {
  override def toString = "In test "+x
}
object Main extends App {

  val test = None
  val b = test.getOrElse({
    println("not found")
    new Test(-1)
  })
  println(b.toString)

}
```